# Artinian rings and PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Suppose that $R$ is a principal ideal domain, and $0\ne t\in R$. I'm trying to show that $R/Rt$ is an artinian $R$-module, and so is an artinian ring if $t$ is not a unit in $R$.
I'm not sure how to begin. please help.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Show that the ideals of $R/Rt$ are all principal, and in fact, are in bijection with the divisors of $t$ in $R$ (considered up to multiplication by a unit). Then use  that $R$ is a UFD (since it's a PID). Finally, note that the ideals of $R/Rt$ are also precisely its $R$-submodules.

Comment: is this true, if R is a PID then R/I is a PID, and what do you mean by divisors of t.

Comment: It's certainly not true if $I$ is not a prime ideal, since then $R/I$ is not a domain. But if $R$ is a PID, then it is always true that every ideal of $R/I$ is principal, and hence, if $I$ is a prime ideal, we will also have that $R/I$ is a PID.

Comment: Regarding divisors: for any ring $R$ and $a,b\in R$, we say that $a\mid b$ when there is some $c\in R$ such that $b=ac$. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)).

Comment: so to make sure I understand, if R is PID and I is a prime ideal then R/I is a PID, correct?

Comment: @Val: Yes, that's true. See [this math.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/32143/264) for example.

Answer (score 4):

It happens that I recently incorporated a more general result into [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf) ($\S 18.3$ on the Krull-Akizuki Theorem).

**Lemma**: For a Noetherian integral domain $R$, the following are equivalent:
(i) $R$ has Krull dimension at most one: i.e., nonzero prime ideals are maximal.
(ii) For every nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$, $R/I$ is an Artinian ring.
(iii) For every nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$, $R/I$ is a finite length $R$-module.

Note that (ii) $\iff$ (iii) and (iii) $\implies$ (i) are almost immediate.  The OP asks about (i) $\implies$ (ii) in the special case that $R$ is a PID.  The proof of (i) $\implies$ (ii) is still pretty easy when $R$ is a Dedekind domain: e.g. one can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and localization to reduce to the case of a PID and reason as Zev does in his answer.  In general though the proof I came up with of (i) $\implies$ (ii) was a bit more technical than I would like.  Maybe someone can suggest something simpler.

Comment: For $(i)\Longrightarrow(ii)$ why don't use Theorem 8.33 (Akizuki)?

Comment: $@$YACP: That sounds promising.  Could you say a little more?

Comment: $R/I$ is noetherian and its Krull dimension is zero since any prime containing $I$ is nonzero, hence maximal.

Comment: @YACP: Well, I'm glad I asked, since that's indeed much easier!

Comment: @YACP: By the way, if you let me know your real name, I will include you in the acknowledgements.

Comment: @Pete Clark Can you clarify 2) implies 3) in Lemma 18.4 of your notes? THanks

Comment: @user65302 I'm not Pete Clark, but I can give you some explanations: $R/I$ is an artinian ring, hence noetherian. But the ideals of $R/I$ coincide with the $R$-submodules of $R/I$, and therefore $R/I$ is an artinian and noetherian $R$-module.

Comment: @user63503: YACP is exactly right.  In other words, a commutative ring $R$ has finite length as an $R$-module if (and only if) it is Artinian.

Comment: @ PeteClark. In your notes you say that every finitely generated module over an Artinian ring is also Noetherian and hence of finite length. Now $R/I$ is a finitely generated module, and hence is both Artinian and a Noetherian module because by assumption $R/I$ is an Artinian ring. Hence the module $R/I$ has finite length as an $R/I$ module. We want to prove this as an $R$ module. So YACP's second comment is more useful in this situation, but is there an easy way to see that?

Comment: @user63503: Any $R/I$-module is an $R$-module of a certain type, namely in which every element of $I$ acts as zero.  It follows that the length over $R/I$ of any $R/I$-module is the same as its length over $R$.