# Quotient of a PID by a prime ideal is a PID too.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I am trying to prove that if $R$ is a PID and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ then $R/P$ is also a PID.
This is question 8.2.3 from Dummit & Foote.

My thoughts and what I know : $P$ is also maximal. $R/P$ is hence a field. Also is an integral domain due $P$ being prime. $P$ is generated by by some element of $R$, say $a$, written as $P=(a)$. My conjecture is that an ideal $I$ of $R/P$ is generated by the coset $a+P$, ie. $I=(a+P)$.

I am having some trouble understanding that the set $I$ is equal to a set generated by a coset. I'm not sure how to show the inclusions to show that those two sets are the same. Any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "$P$ is also maximal": No, $P$ might be the zero ideal.

Comment: I waffled on closing this [as a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32143/29335) because it's debatable that the user's main question is distinct from the title question. Need to have the dupes linked as related this way.

Comment: @Georges, thanks for pointing that out. I need to be more careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted all prime ideals in a PID are maximal and hence the quotient R/P is a field. We know that all fields are Euclidean domains and hence PIDs.

Comment: Perfect. I was missing that a filed is a ED. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. Glad I could help!

Comment: 1)  "all prime ideals in a PID are maximal"  No: the zero ideal is prime but not maximal. 2) That a field is a PID is completely trivial  since its only ideals are itself and the zero ideal. Euclidean domains are irrelevant.

Comment: Showing that a field is a PID by taking a circuit around the notion of an euclidean domain seems very weird to me.

Comment: The nonzero ideal part of your comment is you being pedantic.

Comment: Yes it is irrelevant but it is informatative if you OP did not know the inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other given answer, you can split this into two parts.

First show that in any quotient of a PID all ideals are principal (just take the image of a generator under the canonical homomorphism).

Next, the quotient by a prime ideal is always an integral domain.

Putting these together, we see that if $R$ is a ring where all ideals are principal and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$ then $R/P$ is a PID (so we could even relax the condition on the original ring a bit).